# Selenium Java throws Socket exception (warning) without cause

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I get a "warning" in an onError method in Selenium, using it in a Java application (using Spring Batch Framework). I can't detect what and why it's throwing this error.

This produces when I use the `quit()` method of [ChromeDriver](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chromium/ChromiumDriver.html#quit()) class. When I try to debug, this exception is not thrown.

```
Starting ChromeDriver 110.0.5481.77 (65ed616c6e8ee3fe0ad64fe83796c020644d42af-refs/branch-heads/5481@{#839}) on port 58642
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
[1678747030.900][WARNING]: virtual void DevToolsClientImpl::AddListener(DevToolsEventListener *) subscribing a listener to the already connected DevToolsClient. Connection notification will not arrive.
[2m2023-03-13 23:37:10.946[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m15264[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ null to remote][0;39m [36mo.o.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Detected dialect: W3C
[2m2023-03-13 23:37:10.993[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m15264[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.o.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Found exact CDP implementation for version 110
[2m2023-03-13 23:38:33.789[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m15264[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.b.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Executing batch with 1 items.
[2m2023-03-13 23:39:19.811[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m15264[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.b.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Executing batch with 1 items.
[2m2023-03-13 23:39:19.856[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m15264[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[cHttpClient-1-4][0;39m [36mo.a.netty.handler.WebSocketHandler      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m onError

java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:394) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:426) ~[na:na]
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:258) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

My code from ChromeDriver:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src\\main\\resources\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--headless=new");
ChromeDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            
chromeDriver.get("https://www.google.com/");
//select web items, interact with them
chromeDriver.quit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you get a `java.net.SocketException: Connection reset` error message, this means that something happened to the connection between two ends of the socket. This about when you're watching a video online, then you change your WiFi networkd – you get a similar error.

More specifically, with your issue, you are quitting while the WebSocket is still open. You must first terminate the web socket connection between the `ChromeDriver` and the browser before calling `quit()`.

Your issue is not a "Warning" as you claimed. The "warnings" are not actually a part of the issue, but they still have value. The actual error is the following:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:394) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:426) ~[na:na]
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:258) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

... but the warnings that came before tell me two things:

1. You are attempting to open a duplicate connection with the Chrome browser
2. The first connection is not terminated.

You essentially have two connections between the chrome driver and the browser. When you call `quit()`, Selenium must close its connection with the browser, and this happens only once.

You can either manually close both connection before invoking `quit()` (which I don't know how to do), or you can go through your code (or use a debugger) to find where the second connection is attempting to be established.